# Linux: Howto setup one application to use different sound card?

Tags: linux, audio, simultaneous

I have 3 sound cards - one integrated (A) and 2 on USB (B,C). 
I want play default system sounds over integrated card (A), 
while application 1 over B card and application 2 over C card.
Say, Firefox on B and Chrome on C, all other on default A.

LinuxMint.

Comment: I managed to config 2 virtualboxes to play sound throught card B and C, while default plays on A, but cannot setup this on one system.

Answer (score 0):

ok, I found: apt install pavucontrol :)